# Как лучше принимать данные. (Android)

Tags: android, php, java, javascript, mysql

Имею кучу таблиц в БД на сервере.

1. Сделать приложение на Android и там с HttpGet и т.д получать данные и выводить в TextView.
2. Сделать обычный Веб-браузер в android, а на сайте отдельно отдел для телефона, и там будет страница управления под Мобильный вид. (все запросы управления с AJAX JQuery)

Как лучше для приложения, и где быстрее быстродействие? 1-й способ мне кажется лучше, но 2-й намного легче.

Comment: второй способ известен как PhoneGap. Но может просто сделать сайт и не переживать? Пользователь прекрасно может открыть в браузере. Более того, можно и ярлык на рабочий стол страницы сделать.

Comment: Просто приложение, ну там заказы делать и т.д, то есть из списка выбирать товар, и делать его заказ и т.д, пойдет ли это в PhoneGap ?

Comment: phonegap - это прежде всего доступ к железу устройства из javascript'а (gps, акселерометр, камера и т.д.). друг ваш предложил вот это http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Собственно говоря, вопрос поставленный вами и есть суть дилеммы стоящей перед индустрией в целом:

1. Развитие продолжается в сторону нативных (ну или managed) приложений
2. Либо же браузеры начинают претендовать на традиционные функции ОС (например ChromeOS или широко разрекламированный ОС Tizen)

Второе направление принято обозначать термином **html5** в широком смысле.

Вопрос состоит только в том верите ли вы в то, что браузеры скоро возьмут на себя функции операционных систем или нет?

Я не верю и считаю это вредным. Это примерно то же самое, что и пытаться сделать из велосипеда автомашину. Извратиться можно, но машина все равно будет лучше.

Answer (score 1):

Тут и думать нечего, как не извращайтесь webview все равно будет тормозить, разница между ним, или PhoneGap и нативным приложением огромна

Comment: но для определенного круга задач вполне достаточно обычного вебВью.    
На пример, когда у программиста совсем нет знаний Андроид ОС, а нужно под нее сделать приложение.